# ruby on rails regular expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails application i have a generic search to display the matching results. What I  have done to produce matching results is to replace blank spaces by  "%" symbol. Its working perfectly but only if there is a gap between the search term . If I enter a single word it says "no matching string".

```
class TweetsController<ApplicationController
  def index
    city = params[:show]
    search_term = params[:text]        
    search_term[" "] = "%"

    city_coordinates = Coordinates.where('city=?', city)
    @tweets = if (city_coordinates.count == 1 && city_coordinates.first.valid_location?)                     
        Tweets.for_coordinates(city_coordinates.first) &  Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?" ,"%#{search_term}%").all                     
      else if (Coordinates.count != 1 )
        Tweets.for_user_location(city) & Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE ?" , "%#{search_term}%").all
      else
        @tweets = Tweets.where("%tweet_text% LIKE ? ", "%#{search_term}%").all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting output only if I type two words  like "Harbhajan Singh", "VVS Laxman" . If I type a single word its saying no matching strings. Anybody help me with this. I need the output both ways   the user enters  single word or  two words or more .Anybody help me with this.

Comment: On a side note, consider using Solr for user searches. Your approach will always produce poor results.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you are getting an

```
IndexError: string not matched
```

Thats because when there is a single word coming in params[:text], this code

```
search_term[" "] = "%"
```

raises the error.

You might want to read the string [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) for more details. It states:

> If the regular expression or string is used as the index doesn’t match a position in the string, IndexError is raised.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too great with regular expressions myself, so I usually turn to [Rubular](http://rubular.com). It helps you build and test regular expressions for Ruby.

Comment: However, the code in this question uses SQL `LIKE` expressions, which have a very different syntax from Ruby regular expressions. So Rubular won’t help here.